# how convert Object to int only digit in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my datafarame with pandas

```
2020-02-05
2020-03-02
```

I wanna convert to int for plot to bar histogram chart. So i use regular expression to get only digit. after that i will try to convert int. but my regular expression function get error.

below function is to get digit in string

```
import re

def split_it(data):
    return re.findall('(\d+)',data)[0]
```

and this is my error

```
expected string or bytes-like object
```

so i try again with another source code.

```
import re

def split_it(data):
    return re.findall('(\d+)',str(data))
```

and result it's below.

```
[2020, 02, 05]

[2020, 03, 02]

[2020, 02, 19]
```

#### would you tell me how can i get 20200205 as type int?

#### and why second function is return list type?

Comment: ```int(data.replace('-',''))``` will give you "20200205 as type int" if ```data = '2020-02-05'```.

Answer (score 3):

that doesnt look like a dataframe and you dont show us how you call it but here is how i would do it

```
series = pandas.to_datetime(['2020-02-05','2020-03-02'])
#this is actually a datetimeindex, that does not use .dt accessor
new_series = series.strftime("%Y%m%d").astype(int)
```

if it is a dataframe you would do it slightly different

```
#assumes a column named datetime exists, use its .dt accessor
int_series = df['datetime'].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d").astype(int)
```

Comment: when i was use to_datatime, i get result as like 2020.02.05 so i  can't use astype(int) with ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2020.02.05'

Comment: you missed a step ... look closely at the line with astype(int)

Comment: i get the AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime' would you tell me why?

Comment: you will need to use the `.dt` accessor  `series.dt.strftime`  this is why you need to really show your input well

Answer (score 2):

Try with `replace`

```
data['col'].str.replace('-','').astype(int)
```

Comment: thats a great solution :)  assuming its all just dates and no datetimes it should totally work ... and probably a bit faster than strftime  (assuming the column type supports str)

Comment: if it's have NaN value , should i changed some different data

Comment: @YangDongJae you may check all value in your column follow the same format xxxx-xx-xx